# C# DataFrame LoadCsv - Access denied

Tags: c#, dataframe, csv

I would like to import a CSV file as DataFrame with the DataFrame object (Microsoft.Data.Analysis). But there I get the error message:

"Access to the path 'D:\test.csv' is denied".

```
DataFrame dataFrame = DataFrame.LoadCsv(this.Path);
```

Where can I obtain this authorization?

Comment: Run your app as administrator possibly will solve this problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, that did not work out. I think the problem was that I did it within a UWP app. There the local file access works differently, which I did not know...

Answer (score 1):

If someone should have the same problems, I have solved it in a UWP app as follows:

```
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Downloads;
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".csv");

Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if(file != null)
{
var csvFile = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
DataFrame dataFrame = DataFrame.LoadCsv(csvFile);
}
```